Python binance-us doesn't return most recent klines / candles
I am trying to get recent candles from binance us. However, it doesn't return the most recent data and only returns from July of 2023.
First, here is my code:
def get_candles(self, symbol = "BTCUSD", interval = "1h", end_time = round(time.time()) * 1000):
    data = requests.get(f'https://api.binance.us/api/v3/klines?symbol={symbol}&interval={interval}&endTime={end_time}').json()
    data = pandas.DataFrame(data)

    data[0] = pandas.to_datetime(data[0], unit = 'ms')
    data = data.set_index(0)
    return data

It didn't seem to work so I added the endTime variable as the most recent time but that doesn't work either. Then, I tried pre-existing libraries such as python-binance:
api = binance.Client("", "", tld = 'us')
data = api.get_klines(symbol = "BTCUSD", interval = "1h")
print(pandas.DataFrame(data))

and I also tried this:
api = binance.Client("", "", tld = 'us')
data = api.get_historical_klines(symbol = "BTCUSD", interval = "1h")
print(pandas.DataFrame(data))

but the result was the same:
499  1689300000000  25602.26000000  26459.02000000  24900.00000000  25073.21000000  30.95583000  1689303599999  782941.89073780  4359  6.47354000  165018.00481080  0
(first column is time, second is price, current price of bitcoin is 58000)
Any ideas?
